# How to solve error An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out error in symfony 4 project deployed on amazon aws

Tags: mysql, connection, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, symfony4, php-7

My symfony project is working fine on localhost . i am **able to connect to amazon aws rds** on localhost .I have set mysql configuration in **.env** file of the symfony project .
when i have uploaded/deployed the same project on the amazon-aws . 
i am getting this error :

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

Question:
How can i debug this error ?
Is this issue is related to the amazon aws configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple places it is stopping to connect to rds. Following might be some of the reasons:

- AWS Server outbound rule might be stopping to connect to the rds. If it is in a different security group or vpc.
- RDS Secruity group inbound rules it might not be allowing to connect to the aws server.

You can try connect to rds from the server by using mysql command line.

Comment: Hi.. i am able to connect to the rds using mysql workbench but my project is not able to connect to the database on amazon aws.